# WPF + Prism + EF outside Visual Studio Error

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, entity-framework, .net-4.0, prism

My app was built on .NET 4.0 with WPF, Prism, Entity Framework

There are 1 exe (the app), 1 exe (the app config - simple app to restore db, no referenced dll no prism and no EF), and several referenced DLLs like the prism-way, SQL Server 2008 Express. All assemblies and Exe are built with target platform AnyCpu.

I tested in my development environment(Win764bits, VS2010, .NET4...), no problem. Then I tested in Windows 7 32 bits and the app config works well. But the app runs perfectly only if the Visual Studio is installed. Without VS 2010, I got the 2 errors in event log:

**Application Error:**
Faulting application name: App.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x4df473d0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdaae
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00009617
Faulting process id: 0xa28
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc2aa91326a10e
Faulting application path: C:......\Release\App.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 52f2c510-969c-11e0-98bf-000c299e51f4

**.NET Runtime:**
Application: App.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializeException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.HandleModuleInitializationError(Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo, System.String, System.Exception)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInitializer.Initialize(Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleInfo)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModulesThatAreReadyForLoad()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModuleTypes(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.LoadModulesWhenAvailable()
   at Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Modularity.ModuleManager.Run()
   at ...

I've searched and tried to fix, but It's the same.

Please help me
Many thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that one of my DLL using ReportViewer. Just installed this one and the problem was resolved

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/confirmation.aspx?id=6442